# EditText not staying on top of SoftKeyboard

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

The problem is simple :

- The application is set to SensorLanscape
- The activity is set to adjustResize
- The application is fullscreen with this style

  ```
  <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
      <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
  </style>
  ```
- A dialogFragment is fullscreen with this style

  ```
  <style name="liteMode_Dialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
      <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
  </style>
  ```
- The layout of the dialog is simple let's say a RelativeLayout
- The EditText is initially set to visibility gone or invisible
- When clicking on a button the EditText is made visible then the softkeyboard is shown programmatically

**Result** : The EditText stay at the bottom of the screen

- This time the EditText is initially set to visible

**Result** : The EditText comes up with the softkeyboard

Comment: As I specified : "The EditText is initially set to visibility gone or invisible" same result with both

Comment: If The EditText stay at the bottom of the screen,can you scroll up and find it?

Comment: @An-droid I meant set the alpha set to 0 and 1 when you are showing it again, I am not gonna recommend it

Comment: This is kind of specific, the screen must not be scrollable. Just a background image and a button to make the edittext appear with keyboard

Comment: If it's a specific case, we're gonna need to see more code - fragment, activity with their layouts.

Comment: Using the alpha is a good trick, I think it works thanks you can add the answer